# How to prevent my post showing on the Newsfeed?

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline, news-feed

I posted an old video on my Facebook, but I don’t want others to know I posted it, so I hid it from my timeline. However, I found out that the post is still showing in the newsfeed. I just don’t want people to know I have posted that video, but I want anyone to watch it if they somehow click on my album.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that would be possible.

But try uploading the video to your album with the privacy setting of view only to me. After uploading wait for 1-2 days and change the privacy as view only to friends or friends of friends.

Comment: Well... That's what I'm thinking... However, I need to share that video in someone's post(comment)
What I want is only those people seeing that post I share the video knows but not everyone else